# Russian translation for "it made me feel good (bad)"

Tags: лексикон, перевод, одним-словом

I cannot find a good way to translate such expressions as *It made me feel good (bad)*.

Russian verb *заставить* means to make somebody do something against their will, and doesn't really fit here.

Verbs such as *опечалить* and *обрадовать* are very good translations for phrases such as *it makes me feel sad (happy)*. Are there appropriate verbs for *It made me feel good (bad)* examples?

Comment: "Стало легко на душе". It's not a translation of course but something close...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the verb *стать* here

> Мне (от этого) стало хорошо/плохо/весело/грустно.

I think it's a pretty accurate translation of *It makes/made/will make me feel ...* in all the tenses:

> It makes me feel sad. От этого мне становится грустно.
>
> It made me feel sad. От этого мне стало грустно.
>
> It will make me feel sad. От этого мне станет грустно.
>
> It would make me feel sad. От этого мне стало бы грустно.

Comment: Good synonym for "плохо" is "дурно": "от этого мне стало дурно".

Answer (score 4):

Russian people uses "похорошело" и "поплохело". For example:
First glass of beer made me feel good.
От первого бокала пива мне похорошело.

But next bottle of whiskey mad me feel bad.
Но от следующей бутылки виски мне поплохело.

I'm not sure that this variant is 100% correct and corresponds to Russian grammar but it's usable and everyone will understand you.

Comment: While похорошело and поплохело are valid Russian words, they are much more often used in colloquial speech and rarely seen in literature other than when quoting such colloquial speech.

Comment: похорошеть is used more frequently to refer to improvement in one's appearance, e.g. он похорошел = he looks better

Comment: +1 Также пришло в голову близкое "полегчало".